# Trouble seeing how Lagrange Multipliers are True

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

So if a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ constrained to the surface $g(x)=c$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has a local maximum at $P$, then I'm having trouble seeing how this implies that the gradients of $f$ and $g$ at $P$ point in the same direction.

My intuitive understanding is that there exist $n-1$ orthogonal directions in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are perpendicular to $\triangledown g$, and thus either $g$ is locally constant in all of these directions or has a local extrema in some of these directions.

If $g$ is locally constant in all of these directions, then $f$ must have a derivative of zero in all of these directions and thus we conclude that the gradients of $f$ and $g$ are parallel, but what if $g$ has a local extrema in some of these directions? then there is no need for the derivative of $f$ to be zero in those directions, and thus $\triangledown f$ need not be perpendicular to those directions.

Is this something that doesn't happen for functions with continuous partial derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all boils down to one thing being tangent to another.

Let's take a really simply example. Let's try to find the extrema of the the function $\mathrm{f} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, given by $\mathrm{f}(x,y) = x+y$, subject to the constraint $\mathrm{g}(x,y)=0$ where $\mathrm{g}(x,y)=x^2 + 4y^2 - 1$.

The level-sets $\mathrm{f}^{-1}(v) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \mathrm{f}(x,y)=v\}$ are given by the lines $x+y=v$. The constraint $x^2+4y^2=1$ means that we're interested in the ellipse shown below. I've also included the lines $x+y=v$ where $v=0, \pm 0.5, \pm 1, \pm 1.5$. **Keep reading below the picture!**

[image]

The minima (resp. maxima) are given by the lines $x+y=v$ which have the smallest (resp. largest) possible values for $v$ and which still meet the ellipse, i.e. satisfy the constraint. These are exactly the tangent lines! See below.

[image]

The level-sets were given by the equations $\mathrm{f}(x,y)=v$ and so the gradient $\nabla\mathrm{f}$ gives a vector perpendicular to the level-sets. The ellipse was given by the equation $\mathrm{g}(x,y)=0$ and so the gradient $\nabla\mathrm{g}$ gives a vector perpendicular to the ellipse. Since both $\nabla\mathrm{f} \neq {\bf 0}$ and $\nabla\mathrm{g} \neq {\bf 0}$ it follows that the ellipse and the lines are tangent if and only if $\nabla\mathrm{f}$ and $\nabla\mathrm{g}$ are parallel.

The same idea holds for higher dimensions and more complicated functions.

Having $\nabla\mathrm{f}$ parallel to $\nabla\mathrm{g}$ implies tangency.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the extremum occurs at the point $x^*$. Then take any (smooth) path $x(t)$ which goes through that point and stays entirely on the surface $g=c$. Since $f$ achieves an extreme value at $x^*$ we must have $$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=x'(t)\cdot\nabla f(x(t))=0$$ Since the path $x(t)$ is contained in the level surface of $g$, the gradient of $g$ is orthogonal to it at that point - and so if the gradiant of $f$ by the argument above. Therefore they must be parallel.

I think what's tripping you up is the idea that "If $g$ is locally constant in all of these directions, then $f$ must have a derivative of zero in all of these directions". This is not true. It *is* true that $g$ has zero directional derivative in $n-1$ directions, but we are not composing the functions $f\circ g$ (which is not even possible) so the fact that $g$ doesn't change in those directions does not necessarily mean that $f$ stays fixed as well.